# Windows Phone 7 - Testing for Data Connection

Tags: windows-phone-7

My app failed certification today and the reason was:

> "The application can be caused to
>   silently terminate when the device has
>   no data connection available."

I didn't even think about that when I developed the app.  How do I test for no data connection?  Is there a method that I can call or do I just wrap a try catch around my web service call and try to "catch-it" that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try-catch seems to be the best way, as the data connection could go down between the time you check for it and the time you try to use it. Even if it's the next line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest you need to handle exceptions (try..catch..finally) that can occur under all operating conditions.

With regard to detecting the state of the network connection you can use GetIsNetworkAvailable() and NetworkInterfaceType.

Be aware of developments in this post if using the latter.

[Reading NetworkInterfaceType can take over 20 seconds](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/66651.aspx)